# ANDROID - How do I refresh a listview inside a widget?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-widget

I am building an android app with eclipse and I have a widget that displays a listview that has a button in each for for capturing row item and saving to sqlite db. I am trying to figure out how to update the list whenever the user updates the list in the main app or if they click the refresh imageview I have on the widget. Below are the following classes/files used for the widget. I tried searching everywhere and all the solutions don't seem to work for a listview widget with a service. Any help is greatly appreciated!

WidgetProvider.class

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

DBHelper pdh;
public static final String ACTION_TOAST = "actionToast";
public static final String ACTION_BUTTON = "actionButton";
public static final String EXTRA_ITEM_POSITION = "extraItemPosition";
SimpleDateFormat sdfFinal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat stf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context, appWidgetIds[i]);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        Intent clickIntentRefresh = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
        clickIntentRefresh.setAction(ACTION_BUTTON);
        
        PendingIntent clickPendingIntentRefresh = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, clickIntentRefresh, 0);
        
        Intent clickIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
        clickIntent.setAction(ACTION_TOAST);
        PendingIntent clickPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, clickIntent, 0);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ivRefresh,clickPendingIntentRefresh);
        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingIntent);
        remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.listViewWidget, clickPendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);

    }
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (ACTION_TOAST.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String s = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ITEM_POSITION);

        pdh = new DBHelper(context);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        String strDateStamp = sdfFinal.format(cal.getTime());
        String strTimeStamp = stf.format(cal.getTime());
        pdh.insertRecord(s, null, strDateStamp, strTimeStamp);

        Toast.makeText(context, "Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else if (ACTION_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Refresh Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}

private RemoteViews updateWidgetListView(Context context, int appWidgetId) {

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

    Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);

    svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

    remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.listViewWidget, svcIntent);
    remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.listViewWidget, R.id.empty_view);

    return remoteViews;

}
```

}

WidgetService.class

```
public class WidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {
/*
 * So pretty simple just defining the Adapter of the listview here Adapter is
 * ListProvider
 */

@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
    return (new ListProvider(this.getApplicationContext(), intent));
}
```

}

ListProvider.class

```
public class ListProvider implements RemoteViewsFactory {

public static final String EXTRA_ITEM_POSITION = "extraItemPosition";
private ArrayList<ListItem> listItemList = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
private Context context = null;
private Intent intent;

public ListProvider(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.intent = intent;
    this.context = context;
    intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

    populateListItem();
}

private void populateListItem() {
    try {
        DBHelper pdh = new DBHelper(context);

        listItemList.clear();
        
        SQLiteDatabase db = pdh.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] columns = new String[] { "Categories" };
        Cursor c = db.query("tblCategories", columns, null, null, null, null, "Categories asc");

        int categoriesInt = c.getColumnIndex("Categories");

        int totalCategories = c.getCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < totalCategories; i++) {
            c.moveToPosition(i);
            ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
            listItem.heading = c.getString(categoriesInt);
            listItemList.add(listItem);
        }

        c.close();
        db.close();
        pdh.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listItemList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

/*
 * Similar to getView of Adapter where instead of View we return RemoteViews
 *
 */
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    try {           
        final RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_row);
        ListItem listItem = (ListItem) listItemList.get(position);
        remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.heading, listItem.heading);

        Intent fillIntent = new Intent();
        fillIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_ITEM_POSITION, listItem.heading);
        remoteView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.button1, fillIntent);

        return remoteView;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

ListItem.class

```
public class ListItem {

public String heading;
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <receiver android:name=".WidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widgetinfo" />
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".WidgetService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />
```

Comment: "I tried searching everywhere" -- [the documentation seems to cover this subject](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets/collections?hl=en#keep-data-fresh).

Comment: The refresh button on the widget seems to work only after I close the main app.